# Yellow Triangle Message

Tags: ssl, https

I am the owner of myhomeworkhelp.com and we had taken SSL certificate for our business website. We are getting **Yellow Triangle Messages** in all webpages, but the main problem is if you will open my website on Firefox, Torrent and IE it will not give **Yellow Triangle Message** but when we come on Chrome, it gives **Yellow Triangle Message**. We tried to find a solution for this. We had talked hosting company, SSL provider and our website developer, but every one saying all is fine. Can you help me to fix this issue?

Let me know if you have question

Answer (score 1):

Your certificate uses old unsafe security setting (SHA1 signature) and Google Chrome decided to warn about it since Jan 1.

Ask for a new SSL certificate with SHA256 signature.

Comment: Everything going very costly, I will think and will change our current plan. Thank you very much!

Comment: You can upvote and mark my answer as correct to help people finding help with the same problem :)

Answer (score 1):

you may find the following useful:

https://support.servertastic.com/the-site-is-using-outdated-security-settings-that-may-prevent-future-versions-of-chrome-from-being-able-to-safely-access-it/

&

https://support.servertastic.com/deprecation-of-sha1-and-moving-to-sha2/

On chrome its just a warning to let you know that they are transitioning to SHA-2 ( SHA256 ) support and notifying about the older less secure methods used by your existing SHA1 cert.

All is currently fine but you may want to move stuff over to 256 to remove the triangle on chrome, it will probably happen on other browsers soon as well. :)